# VS code has the wrong ipython directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My ipython version on mac terminal and on VS code terminal are different. I have different packages installed in both. And this is confirmed when I do which python, I get:

❯ which ipython

```
/usr/local/bin/ipython
```

and

❯  which ipython

```
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/ipython
```

in the other. How can I fix this? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are different versions of Python in your system, one is a Global environment, and the other is a Virtual Environment (anaconda).

You can read [document about environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_python-environments) in VsCode-Python.

In your issue, you can use **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to switch to the other python environment.

[image]